# Hints to make Sudoku solver more Pythonic (II)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sudoku

I tried to implement as many changes suggested as possible as well as expanding the code base according to the suggested link. The original question can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56558/hints-to-make-sudoku-solver-more-pythonic). It does solve 4x4 and 9x9 Sodukus.

What should I do to make it more Pythonic?

This is what I came up with:

```
from numpy import *
import sys

TEXT = '.123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
NUMBER = arange(len(TEXT)+1)

## Read the file in
def read(name):
    with open(name) as fid:
        str = fid.read().replace('\n',"")
    s = int(sqrt(len(str)))

    # check input
    if s != int(sqrt(s))**2:
        raise Exception("Input needs to be quadratic")

    if len(str.strip(TEXT[0:s + 1])) != 0:
        raise Exception("Do not use anything beside %s with this base" % TEXT[0:s + 1])
    return (str,s)

## Set the value in field and adjust the possibility tensor
def set(col,row,wert,feld,pos,s):
    if feld[col,row] != 0:
        raise Exception

    pos[col,row,:] = 0
    pos[:,row,wert] = 0
    pos[col,:,wert] = 0

    ss = int(sqrt(s))

    col_start = col // ss * ss
    row_start = row // ss * ss
    pos[col_start:col_start + ss,row_start:row_start + ss,wert] = 0

    feld[col,row] = wert + 1

## Read in the stuff and create field
def read_and_construct(name):
    str,s = read(name)
    feld = zeros((s,s),dtype=uint8)
    pos = ones((s,s,s),dtype=bool_)

    for ind in range(s**2):
        if str[ind] is not '0' and str[ind] is not '.':
            set(ind // s,ind % s,NUMBER[TEXT.index(str[ind])] - 1,feld,pos,s)
    return (feld,pos,s)

## Write the output into a file
def write(name,feld,s):
    with open(name,'w') as fid:
        for col in range(s):
            for row in range(s):
                fid.write(TEXT[feld[col,row]])
            fid.write('\n')

## Are we there yet?
def done(feld,s):
    return count_nonzero(feld) == s**2

## Start the Analytical Process returns 0 if solved
def anal(feld,pos,s):
    neu = 1
    while neu:
        neu = 0

        # Scan all dimensions of pos 
        ind = where(sum(pos,axis = 2) == 1)
        for x,y in zip(ind[0],ind[1]):      
            set(x,y,nonzero(pos[x,y,:])[0][0],feld,pos,s)

        ind = where(sum(pos,axis = 1) == 1)
        for x,y in zip(ind[0],ind[1]):      
            set(x,nonzero(pos[x,:,y])[0][0],y,feld,pos,s)

        ind = where(sum(pos,axis = 0) == 1)
        for x,y in zip(ind[0],ind[1]):      
            set(nonzero(pos[:,x,y])[0][0],x,y,feld,pos,s)   

        # get the box
        for x in range(s):
            for y in range(s):
                col_start = x // s * s
                row_start = x % s * s

                if sum(pos[col_start:col_start + s,row_start:row_start + s,y]) == 1:
                    ind = nonzero(pos[col_start:col_start + s,row_start:row_start + s,y]);
                    neu = set(col_start + ind[0][0],row_start + ind[1][0],y,feld,pos,s)

## A brute force method to calculate the missing values returns 0 if solved
def brute(feld,pos,s):
    # get a starting point with minimum possibilities
    n_pos = sum(pos,axis=2)
    n_pos[n_pos == 0] = 255
    ind = unravel_index(n_pos.argmin(), n_pos.shape)

    # trial and error
    for wert in nonzero(pos[ind[0],ind[1],:])[0]:   
        try_feld = copy(feld)
        try_pos = copy(pos)

        try:
            set(ind[0],ind[1],wert,try_feld,try_pos,s)
            anal(try_feld,try_pos,s)

            if not done(try_feld,s):
                try_feld, try_pos = brute(try_feld,try_pos,s)

            if done(try_feld,s):
                break
        except:
            pass
    return (try_feld, try_pos)

## main method
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        raise Exception("Give path to input and output file")

    feld, pos, s = read_and_construct(sys.argv[1])
    anal(feld,pos,s)

    if not done(feld,s):
        feld,pos = brute(feld,pos,s)

    write(sys.argv[2],feld,s)
```

Comments on the code:

- It's just great that I can use `Exception` to control the program flow. Very nice
- I hope did the file I/O now in a Pythonic way.
- I read that vectorization is good in Python.  Should I try to vectorize the code even further?

Answer (score 3):

Correct idiom for `if not cond: raise Exception(message)` is `assert cond, message`.

Also, don't use builtin names for something else. When I look at str.strip, I see unbound method. :-(

`str[ind] is not '0' and str[ind] is not '.'` is `str[ind] not in '0.'`. And don't use `is` when you mean `==`.

Don't ever use bare `except:`. It catches much more than you think. Either define customized Exceptions subclass, or use assert as I said above.

Comment: To clarify: ["Assertions should *not* be used to test for failure cases that can occur because of bad user input or operating system/environment failures, such as a file not being found."](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) Assertions are for internal consistency checks. In other words, assert conditions that you _know_ to be true, rather than conditions that you _hope_ to be true. For example, `assert len(sys.argv) == 3, "Give path to input and output file"` would definitely not be appropriate.

Comment: A relevant blog on ["the evils of (bare) `except`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/).

Comment: @200_success: If he used precise exceptions (for example, TypeError, ValueError,...), you'd be correct. This way, I stand by my claim that AssertionError is infinitely better than just Exception. Of course they can be turned off, but OP's not gonna do that. :-)